# Finding layouts by id

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Noob here.

I am trying to spawn an image on a button click, in order to do that I took some code from this question: [How do I create an ImageView in java code, within an existing Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994494/how-do-i-create-an-imageview-in-java-code-within-an-existing-layout)
I used the code from the first answer, but In the line:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
```

I don't know what to put instead of "RelativeLayout01", or how to have a layout in "id"

Thanks in advance

Comment: that is the id in your layout xml. do you have a layout with relativelayout with id `RelativeLayout01` in your layout xml

Comment: I know I have to change it to the name of a layout in "id", but I don't know how to make a layout with an id in XML.

Comment: go through the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html instead of asking a question here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`findViewById()` is a method you call on a view you've already inflated from an XML file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/what-does-layout-inflater-in-android-do) for a little more detail on inflating views; also, [the documentation for `findViewById`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))).

The "RelativeLayout01" in this example refers to an id set on the main layout in the XML file related to the `Activity` that contains the click listener you're writing. It's just a placeholder; set an id on the main layout in your `Activity`'s XML file, and use that id in your code to place the image.

Also, if you haven't already, read [the documentation on XML layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html); that should clear up a few things as well. The `android:id` attribute (see the sample XML file; the attribute can be applied to any element) is the one relevant to your question.

Answer (score -1):

After you type 
    R.id.r
press CTRL+space on eclipse, it will try to autocomplete, if you see your variables in the list, then select them, if not then you didn't add them to XML.